# Calculate the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ with $|G| = p^4$ with $|Z(G)|=p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ be a group of order $p^4$ such that $|Z(G)|=p^2$. Calculate the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

I couldn't think of much except for, if $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, then each conjugacy class can be think of as an orbit. By the class equation, we have $$(1) \space p^4=|G|=p^2+\sum |\mathcal O_{x_i}|$$ where the sum is over a representative from each orbit of cardinal greater than 1.

We also $|\mathcal O_{x_i}|=\dfrac{|G|}{|C_G(x_i)|}$, where $C_G(x_i)$ is the centralizer of the element $x_i$. By (1) and by the fact that $x_i \not \in Z(G)$, we have  $|\mathcal O_{x_i}| \in \{p,p^2,p^3\}$.

Here I got stuck, any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\notin Z(G)$, then $C_G(x) \supsetneq Z(G)$ but $C_G(x) \subsetneq G$. Since $[G:Z(G)]=p^2$, we must have $[G:C_G(x)]=p$ for all conjugacy classes. So all conjugacy classes have $p$ elements, and since
$p^4 = p^2 + kp,$ there must be $k = p^3-p$ nontrivial conjugacy classes, so $p^3+p^2-p$ overall (including $Z(G)$).

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! Try to rewrite "So all conjugacy classes have since p", I suppose you've meant all conjugacy classes have p elements.